# API does not run with axios but running with fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am testing a simple API, when I use the fetch method it runs completely fine. The following is the code

```
        fetch(
                `api/putUser`,
                {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    userToken: sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
                    firstName: "John",
                    lastName: "Cena",
                })
        })
```

However the same thing when I change to axios it does not work, what am I missing when using axios? Any help would be appreciated. The axios code is as below:

```
    await axios.put({
    url: "api/putUser",
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: {
        userToken: sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Cena",
    }});
```

Comment: _"when I change to axios it does not work"_ - do you get any error? what's the error message?

Comment: No just that nothing gets updated

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: api_base_url,
    headers: {
        common: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`
        }
    }
})
```

And then, call the method by the code below:

```
const response = await api.put('api/putUser', {
    userToken: sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Cena",
})
```

Note that the `api_base_url` has to substituted by your endpoint base URL.

Hope it helps you out.